# Can I use the SERIAL data type for this?

Tags: database

I am creating a database where one field needs to auto-increment from 1. The field would be for serial numbers. Should I use the "Serial' data type i.e I am using bigint(20) unsigned?

Comment: phpmyadmin is an application, it's **not** a DBMS. But as it is used to manage a MySQL database, let's assume you are using MySQL (although the data type "serial" is a datatype unique to PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends, but probably not. Most businesses want some accounting of the serial numbers they've used. That usually means they want an auditable sequence that has no gaps. The automatic sequences generated by database management systems aren't guaranteed to have no gaps.

The canonical way to handle this is to create a table of serial numbers (or, depending on the application, a table of just the sequential part of a more complex serial number). The application "takes" the next available serial number from that table, and updates that table with some relevant, auditable data. Something like username and timestamp are common, but it really depends on the application.

You need to be careful with production lines that eat thousands of serial numbers per second. That much activity can make contention for the serial number table a problem.